# In Thunderclient, my API is showing "Processing, Please Wait..." and stuck over here

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, thunderclient

[image: Image that shows Processing, Please Wait...]

I am using JavaScript and node js for configuring backend and I want to perform CRUD operations.
What should be the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Same here; I'm only getting it on localhost requests but it's working when replace localhost with [::1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this question.
In index.js file, I need to use app.use(cors()) instead of app.use(cors) .
Because of this, My API is not working. Now, after updating this, Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe response is missing ,cross check if you are sending res.json or any response after api hit.

Comment: Yes, I am sending res.json at the end.